# ASP.net commands to SQL dbo

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I've very new to ASP.net. However, I am currently working on a project and I am trying to change the table that this ASP.net application is pointing to.

I know that the key to doing this lies in figuring out how the following is set in my `Default.aspx.vb` file:

```
Dim cmdText as String = "[up_getPrevention]"
Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(cmdText, conn)
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", usr)
```

Does anyone know what the `[]` means in the statement above? I know that typically the SQL statement (ie. `SELECT`) is within those double quotes...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `up_getPrevention` is probably a stored procedure based on the prefix rather than a table.  The `[]` are optional and are used if the identifier within them contains characters that are reserved (not actually the case here).

Comment: Do you know where the stored procedure may be located? I suppose if I change that, then I can change the `SELECT` query that is embedded in there. What I'm thinking is there the stored procedure links to a `SELECT` query to pulls `Prevention` measures from a table (probably the one I need to change).

Comment: You would look in SQL Server Management Studio, there is a Stored Procedures node under the database name (Right click it to edit).

Comment: Will I need to compile anything after updating the Stored Procedure in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Nope, edit the procedure, run it - F5 - to update it on the server and your done.

Comment: Alex K, thank you so much! That's all I needed to know. Your responses were very helpful and I greatly appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

if the sp name we are writing is a keyword of SQL itself then we need to put [] at start and end of it...

Like 'Table'

Comment: You also need to use them when the name contains spaces or any other bizarre naming convention that people come up with.